# How to show excluded form fields in ModelAdmin?

Tags: python, django

I have a simple `CategoryForm` which has a hidden field that automatically gets added during save on the front-end. In the Admin panel I would like `is_staff` users to be able to add a `Category` while the field is hidden there as well. To superusers I would like the field to be shown. How do I get the excluded fields back in my Admin form?

**Forms.py**:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('category', 'company',)
        exclude = ['company']
        widgets = {'company': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

**Admin.py**:

```
class CustomCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CategoryForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.fields = ('category',)
        else:
            self.fields = ('category', 'company',) # this throws a key error because company is excluded
        return form

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(CustomCategoryAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        company = request.user.company
        form.instance.company.add(company)  # add object to company field while saving
```

Answer (score 0):

What I decided to do was create another form named `AdminCategoryForm` and set the `form = AdminCategoryForm` as an attribute of `CustomCategoryAdmin`.

So now my **Forms.py**:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('category', 'company',)
        exclude = ['company']
        widgets = {
            'company': forms.HiddenInput()
        }


class AdminCategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('category', 'company',)
```

And my **Admin.py**:

```
class CustomCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AdminCategoryForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.fields = ('category',)
        else:
            self.fields = ('category', 'company',)
            self.filter_horizontal = ('company',)

        return form

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(CustomCategoryAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        company = request.user.company
        form.instance.company.add(company)
```

Even though I am repeating my code I feel that this may be the more elegant solution than overriding a `ModelAdmin` method as it becomes much more clear to outside programmers what is going on here.

If anybody else has other solutions I would love to hear..